Apply shell expansion to arguments in run/debug configuration?
I'm working on a Python script, in PyDev, which will be invoked from the command line.  In that environment, shell expansion will be applied to the argument list, which is what I need.
When running or debugging in Eclipse/PyDev, that expansion is NOT applied, making it difficult to test under "real" conditions.
Is there a way to configure PyDev to run or debug within a sub-shell environment where expansion is applied?

Unfortunately, launches from PyDev will not be done in a terminal or have shell expansion.
Some possible alternatives:

Use https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tm-terminal#details to have a terminal inside of Eclipse to run your commands.
Have a python script which would then run the commands you want in the shell (so, you'd get the arguments received and then run the command in the shell you'd like).


Would either of those methods allow the debugger to be used?

Humm, that's a good point, I think you have to use the remote debugger in this case... the auto attach to subprocesses could work in the 2nd case (but it may need some additional heuristics in the debugger in that case, not sure without testing).
